# Unable to login Firebase with cli command

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to login to my Firebase account with cli command `firebase login`. I believe it should open browser and prompt me to login with my google account, but that doesn't seem to happen.

Instead, it's asking me to enter my email and password in the terminal. Once I enter my credentials, it throws the following error:

> /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-cli/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:223
>       return '\n    at ' + wrapCallSite(frame);
>                          ^ TypeError: CallSite method toString expects CallSite as receiver

How do I fix this as I want to deploy my app to Firebase?

Comment: You should open this as an issue on the firebase repository (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk). I am experiencing the same error on `firebase@7.8.0`.

Comment: have you tried updating your firebase cli to the latest version with `npm install -g firebase-tools` ?

Comment: Hi, Panos I already have the latest package.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.  *EDIT* In my case I had accidentally installed the npm package `firebase-cli` instead of `firebase-tools`

Comment: @blaster, yes. That was the problem for me too! Thanks!
God knows what I would do without StackOverflow!

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same issue.

You're probably using `firebase-cli` instead of `firebase-tools`.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli

`firebase-cli` has been deprecated years ago.

> @mikeonline did you ever installed the Firebase tools/cli before on
>   your machine (before we launched v3 at Google IO) basically did you
>   have v2.2 previously installed perhaps?
>
> firebase-cli has been deprecated a year ago and only installs v1. NPM
>   should have printed this message"
>
> npm WARN deprecated firebase-cli@1.2.0: Use firebase-tools instead.
>   Both v2 and v3 can be installed with npm install -g firebase-tools but
>   by default the latest version (3.0.0) gets installed.

https://github.com/firebase/codelab-friendlychat-web/issues/22#issuecomment-220695413

Comment: I'm not using `firebase-cli`. I'm using firebase-tools only. I'm able to login using **CMD**, but not with built in **VS Code** terminal integrated with `ohmyzsh`

Comment: @VinaySharma can you try running `which firebase` on the VS code terminal and the normal terminal? if they're not pointing to the same location then VS code may have a different initialisation setting. I used to have this issue with the integrated terminal in PyCharm where it's using a different $PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the below command

```
npm uninstall firebase-cli
npm uninstall firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools --force
```